# Safety in Karachi, Pakistan

Tags: safety, pakistan, karachi

I certainly don't want to judge by the picture depicted in media (which is not always correct), but is Karachi safe for an Asian foreigner to visit? I am planning to visit, and I need to know the following:

1. Which parts should I avoid?
2. Which parts of the city are generally deemed safe?
3. Is it safe for women (in Pakistani-standard modest attire) and does
   that safety extend to the night?
4. Are the slums extremely dangerous? (I watched a vice documentary on Layari
   recently and it was pretty scary)

Comment: Asian foreigner ? Pakistan is in Asia too ;)

Comment: Sometimes "Asian" means "from the subcontinent", and sometimes it can mean people from countries like China and Japan. Judging by your photo, is it the former?

Comment: As blackbird57 alludes, *Asian* means different things in different places. In North America, an *Asian* phenotype is one typical of East Asia (China, Japan, Korean, etc.) whereas in Britain, an *Asian* is someone from South Asia (India, Pakistan, Bangladesh, etc.); an East Asian there is an *Oriental*, a term which is considered outdated in the U.S. and which some may take as offensive.

Comment: 'Oriental' is (when used to describe a person, as opposed to an antique object such as an oriental vase) considered dated and borderline-offensive here in the UK too. 'Asian' is a very general term here, to be specific one uses the name of the actual country in question.

Comment: it's Sri Lanka :) Adding to the question, We will be staying with a friend of mine, he said it is quite safe. But just wanted to double check. I want to get back in one piece, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I frequently visit Karachi - and even though I am from Pakistan I consider myself an expat since I have lived the majority of my life outside and I am not from Karachi so it adds another layer of unfamiliarity to the situation.

Karachi is a very large metropolis - the largest in Pakistan. It has its safe parts, and it has its rough parts just like every other large city in any country.

Safety depends entirely on the area where you are staying. If its near Clifton or downtown Karachi near the major hotels, then you'll be okay. The major shopping centers and malls are also safe.  Tariq road, for example is constantly busy throughout the night with shoppers.

I would caution against going *anywhere else alone* even for male visitors who are unfamiliar with the area.

Specifically for women - first, I would caution against traveling alone. If you must, only do so using reputable taxi companies like white cab; or arrange for a driver from your hotel (almost all can arrange a car with a driver for you).

Having not ventured into the slums I cannot comment; but on the whole there are areas of Karachi where even the locals caution against going - due to the various sectarian issues; and these ares often come up in such discussions.